# Android Torn Images

Tags: android, camera

I am a newbie in android dev...

I more or less copied the camera implementation from http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html. However, it returns totally torn images like in the image link below. A notable thing is that the icon of that image in windows shows a correct image, therefore, there must be something wrong with the jpeg compression...

Does somebody had the same problem before?

thanks in advance!

lol cannot post images =.= how stupid

Comment: You can upload a picture to an image hosting site and link to it. That'd be not "stupid".

Comment: @user529767 You need a few points before you are able to post images.  I think this is just to prevent image spam.  As EboMike pointed out, you can link to an image hosted elsewhere for now, or just answer a few questions and you'll get enough points quickly.